# find's prune's -path is not taking wildcards

Tags: find, path

i want to exclude one directory from the find search tree. `.aaa` is a hidden sub-directory in the current directory. I want to exclude `aaa_rc_bbb, xxx_rc_xxx` and many more sub-directories containing `rc` in their names. But it still not ignoring and giving me results containing `rc` sub-directories. Its as if `*rc*` wildcard is not working.

`find -L /students/projects/myname/ -name .aaa -prune -o -path */*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/*rc*/ -prune -o -path */*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/bambi/b‌​ambi.txt | head -n50 | xargs ls`.

Also, i want find to search only in this path : `*/*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/bambi/b‌​ambi.txt`

Please help me. Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The first issue is that you have unquoted globs (`*`). All those paths should be surrounded with single quotes, e.g. `'*/*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/bambi/b‌​ambi.txt'`. This prevents the shell from expanding the wildcards before they get passed to `find`.

Next, you need the `-prune` sub-expression to occur before the main search sub-expression. BTW, you can combine all the names into a compound expression with a single `-prune` like this:

```
find \( \( -name '*foo*' -o -name '*bar*' \) -a -prune \) -o \( -name baz -a -print \)
```

This means I want to find files named `baz` while excluding any files/directories containing `foo` or `bar` in their names.

Some notes:

- I'm being liberal with the `-a` (AND) operator and the parentheses so there is no ambiguity.
- Parentheses, which act to change precedence just like with most other expression types, are escaped with `\` so they are not interpreted by the shell before being passed to `find`.
- I'm using two `-name` tests but any other tests (e.g. `-path`) can be in the first nested set of parentheses. Any file/dir matching any of the tests will be pruned and thus not applied to the next tests (in the last set of parens).
- It's a good idea to be explicit with the `-print` action to distinguish it from the `-prune` part.

For clarity let's rewrite this in a more common expression style:

```
((name=='*foo*' OR name=='*bar*') AND prune) OR (name==bar AND print)
```

or even

```
if (name=='*foo*' OR name=='*bar*')
   prune
else if (name==bar)
   print
fi
```

Now given normal precedence rules and that the default boolean operator is `-a` we can reduce the example down to:

```
find \( -name '*foo*' -o -name '*bar*' \) -prune -o -name baz -print
```

Turning to your command, the paths that `find` constructs for the files it discovers will never end in `/` characters, so `-path '*/*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/*rc*/'` could never possibly match. You'd need to drop that trailing `/` and possibly add a `-type d` if you want to restrict to files of type *directory*.

Also note that `*/*` as a pattern matches on any string that contains a `/`, that also includes `foo/bar/baz`. Here, your paths all start with `/students/projects/myname/` so the `/` in `*/*` is redundant as we know already that that `/` will be there.

If I'm reading your intent correctly you don't have any tests for the second sub-expression, i.e. if a file doesn't get pruned you want to print it. So that leads to

```
find -L /students/projects/myname/ \
  \( \
       -name .aaa \
    -o -path '*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/*rc*' \
    -o -path '*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/bambi/b‌​ambi.txt' \
  \) -prune \
  -o -print
```

Comment: @B Layer, I am not understanding `find \( \( -name '*foo*' -o -name '*bar*' \) -a -prune \) -o \( -name baz -a -print \)`
Can you write the same thing in my expression, then i will understand. :-)

Comment: You're welcome. Just do yourself a favor and understand the answer rather than blindly copy the last part.

Comment: Yes, i understood with the notes you just provided, no need to write in my expression, you can delete it.

Comment: Great. I'll leave your example there since it illustrates the concepts (for others who read it.)

Comment: But my problem is not solved, my problem is that `*rc*` is not being read by bash. There are so many directories containing `rc` letter, i want to prune them all.

Comment: Try putting single quotes around all strings with `*`....`'*/*/class_project/etc'`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `-path` pattern ends with a slash.  No pathname that `find` examines will ever end in a slash, so the pattern will never match anything.

To prune any directory called `.aaa` and any directory with `rc` in its name:

```
find -L /students/projects/myname \
    -type d '(' -name '.aaa' -o -name '*rc*' ')' -prune -o -print
```

To only look at the path `*/*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/bambi/b‌​ambi.txt`:

```
find -L /students/projects/myname \
    -type d '(' -name '.aaa' -o -name '*rc*' ')' -prune -o \
    -path '*/*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/bambi/b‌​ambi.txt' -print
```

This assumes that `bambi.txt` is located in

```
/students/projects/myname/*/*/class_project/*/*/pikachu/*/*/bambi/b‌​ambi.txt
```

Note the quoting of the patterns in the `find` command. Without quotes, the shell would try to expand the patterns to lists of pathnames before calling `find`, possibly resulting in confusing `find`, or with some shells, an error.

Comment: Oh, I just edited that into the accepted answer before realising your answer already pointed it out.